# Dynamic link color animation

Tags: dynamic, colors, jquery-animate, hyperlink

I have a div with some links in it. I'm trying to create a dynamic color change trough all of the links when the page is loaded(on ready). In other words, I want each link to go from white to orange and then back to white.
Ex. When the page is loaded link 'first' flashes orange and goes to the link 'second', flashes and goes to the link 'third' and so forth for all of the link inside that div.

If I use 'hover' and this:

```
$(this).animate({ color: "#F50" }, 400);
},function() {
$(this).animate({ color: "#FFFFFF" }, 600);
});
```

It will do what I want it to do but requires hovering. I want it to be automated as someone enters the site.

```
<div id="menu">
       <a class="first" href="#">
       <a class="second" href="#">
       <a class="third" href="#">
    </div>
```

Do you have any ideas, how I would do something like this???
Thanks,
H

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a").delay(1000).ready(function() {
$(".home").delay(500).animate({ color: "#F50" }, 800)
$(".home").animate({ color: "#CCCCCC" }, 1200);

$(".beauty").delay(1000).animate({ color: "#F50" }, 800)
$(".beauty").animate({ color: "#CCCCCC" }, 1200);

$("#about").delay(1500).animate({ color: "#F50" }, 800)
$("#about").animate({ color: "#CCCCCC" }, 1200);
```

So I went with a simple manual way of doing things.